# Particle not showing up in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, volumetrics

I wish to create some dust particles but my particles are not showing up.
I used some generated objects for the matter, put them in a group and use the group for the particles. The size is scaled up to 1.0 but still nothing. You see the particles in wireframe and the objects themselves shaded. I did set the particles to **rendered** but to no avail. I have them in a box that has a volume scatter material. The particles have a translucent shader and the scene is lit using a sun light. 
The two images of the issue:
[image: particle and object]
[image: rendered image]
link to the file:
[image]

Comment: Could you post a [blend?](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: just noticed there is an uploader. editing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the camera ray visibility disabled for cycles on the "particleCube".

[image]

Comment: Blender has lots of settings that control such things. Until you know the ins and outs, you are likely to struggle with *bugs* like this. Glad I could help.